# How to configure TRESTRequest for RAD Server Authentication call?

Tags: rest, delphi

I'm using Delphi Tokyo 10.3 upd 1 with RAD Server.  I deployed some resources/endpoint in RAD Server in a RESTFull architecture and it is working fine, I can access all resources from any browser, Postman REST API tool  and from whithin my Delphi VCL client applicaton using REST.Client library components : TRESTClient, TRESTResquest and TRESTResponse, TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter.

Now I need to go one step further and implement a basic level of security. I'm trying to use RAD Server authentication mechanism.  I configured the emsserver.ini **Server.Keys** session as follows :

```
[Server.Keys]
MasterSecret=mysecret01   
AppSecret=mysecret01   
ApplicationID=mysecret01
```

and implemented the code below for calling the resource/endpoint  :

```
procedure TFRMXTABRecurso.BTGETResourceAuthClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Try
     with DMREST do   // Datamodule where REST Client components are
     begin
         FDMemXTabRec.CachedUpdates := false;
         RstAdapter.Dataset  := FDMemXTabRec;  // my FDmemtable

         RstRequest.ResetToDefaults;
         RstClient.ResetToDefaults;
         RstResponse.ResetToDefaults;
         RstAdapter.ClearDataSet;

         RstClient.BaseURL   := 'http://localhost:8080/';
         RstRequest.Method   := rmGET;
         RstRequest.Resource := 'XTABRECURSO';

         try
             Rstrequest.Params.Clear;
             Rstrequest.AddParameter('X-Embarcadero-App-Secret',    'mysecret01', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
             Rstrequest.AddParameter('X-Embarcadero-Application-Id','mysecret01', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
             Rstrequest.AddParameter('X-Embarcadero-Master-Secret', 'mysecret01', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
             RstRequest.Execute;
         except
            on E: Exception do
             begin
                  raise Exception.Create('Connection problem : ' + sLineBreak + E.QualifiedClassName + sLineBreak + E.Message);
             end;
         end;
     end;
   Finally
       FDMemXTabRec.CachedUpdates := True;
   End;
end;
```

when I run, I got the following ERROR MESSAGE from the RAD EMS Development Server console :

```
{"Error":{"Type":"HTTP","Code":"404","Reason":"Error","Error":"Not found","Description":"Request has unknown application id: mysecret01","Thread":13288}}
```

After checking Embarcadero documentation and videos,  I still could not figure out what is wrong or missing here !!  Is there any missing parameter for the RestRequest ?

Thanks for your help !